# How do I create a new int/String in java?

Tags: java, int

I've tried doing this:

```
String Thomas = new String
```

and

```
int initial_number1 = new int
```

I always get errors so could someone tell me what i am doing wrong or just how to do it?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: `String str = new String("Hello World!");` will work since `String` is a class, though `int number = new int();` will not, `int` is not a class, it is a primitive type, though `int number = new Integer(11)` will work since, __Boxing__ is performed here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Neither of those attempts would do anything useful even if syntactically correct.

Comment: update your code with what you learnt . Right now it welcomes downvotes for its bad syntax

Answer (score 4):

```
String Thomas = "this is a string";
int initial_number1 = 23;
```

For these variable types, you do not need to use `new`. This is because data types like `int` are primitives. `String` is a weird one because it is not actually a primitive. Because of this, you can also do

```
String Thomas = new String("this is a string");
```

Although this way is not recommend for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
String Thomas = new String("hello world");
Integer initial_number1 = new Integer(23);
```

you should have a look on [boxing and unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: `int a = new Integer(23);` too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a String literal or int literal in your examples,

```
String msg = "Hello"; // <-- String literal
int number = 2;       // <-- int literal
System.out.printf("%s %d%n", msg, number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below.

```
 int (anyName) = (anyValue);
 String (anyName);
```